# Any use in supplying FallbackValue to working WPF bindings to eliminate warnings?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, visual-studio-2017

Today I was testing a UserControl which works well.  On a whim, I changed the output window WPF Trace Setting for "Data Binding" from "Warning" to "All" and tested again, just to see what I was missing.

As you might expect, my output window really started filling up with a whole lot of messages.  For example

> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the
>   binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Image; DataItem=null; target element is 'Image'
>   (Name='CurrentImage'); target property is 'Source' (type
>   'ImageSource')

No big deal.  I know the binding works well.  My image shows up just fine  But here is the relevant XAML

```
<!--Image is drawn first, underneath everything else.

<Image x:Name="CurrentImage" 
       Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"
       Source="{Binding Image}"
       Loaded="CurrentImage_OnLoaded"
       />
```

To satisfy my curiosity, I decided to try to eliminate this message with a Fallback value to see if there was any effect..  And I was certainly able to using x:Null (I suppose I could have also use a static resource imagesource...)

```
<Image x:Name="CurrentImage" 
       Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"
       Source="{Binding Image, FallbackValue={x:Null}}"
       Loaded="CurrentImage_OnLoaded"
       />
```

The message went away and the control worked... exactly as it did before.

(This might be a poor example as it's not a "warning" but I also occasionally have "warning" and even "error" level messages appearing from other parts that similarly works just fine all the time.)

So I was wondering:  Is there any real value in eliminating such messages with default values?  Will WPF work any faster or better if I do this regularly?

Or is there some message ***level*** (warning, error, critical informational) at which I should make it my task to do so and beyond which I should ignore these?

Or should I just go back to real problems take these on a case by case basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any real value in eliminating such messages with default values?

No.

> Will WPF work any faster or better if I do this regularly?

You should eliminate any *actual* binding errors in *your* code/markup and let the framework take care of the rest. The framework does produce some harmless binding errors that you can't do much about besides [ignoring or supress them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51838505/7252182).

> Or should I just go back to real problems take these on a case by case basis?

Yes. There is no reason to focus on trying to fix non-issues that you aren't even responsible for in the first place.