# How to eliminate Binding “Information” in WPF output window - cannot retrieve value using the binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am writing a WPF application, and performance is it is a bit slow, and so I am trying to solve it. When I run, I get roughly a gazillion of these types of messages:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=(0); DataItem=null; target element is 'Control' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=AreRowDetailsFrozen; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridDetailsPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation' (type 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HeadersVisibility; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridRowHeader' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=ValidationErrorTemplate; DataItem=null; target element is 'Control' (Name=''); target property is 'Template' (type 'ControlTemplate')
```

If I make a little example application:

```
<Window x:Class="bindingerrors.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:bindingerrors="clr-namespace:bindingerrors" Title="MainWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <bindingerrors:Thinger x:Key="Thing" />               
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="TheGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff, Source={StaticResource Thing}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="!" Binding="{Binding A, FallbackValue=''}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" Binding="{Binding I, FallbackValue=''}" />              
                </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And the following object definitions:

```
public class Thinger
{
    public ObservableCollection<ARow> Stuff { get; private set; }

    public Thinger()
    {
        //Fill up some bogus data
        string letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        int i = 0;
        Stuff = new ObservableCollection<ARow>();
        foreach (var letter in letters)
        {
            Stuff.Add(new ARow(letter.ToString(),i));
            i++;
        }
    }
}

public class ARow
{
    public string A { get; private set; }
    public int I { get; set; }

    public ARow(string a, int i)
    {
        A = a;
        I = i;
    }
}
```

Upon execution, I get mountains of those binding problems. Because many WPF performance articles claim that failed bindings can seriously hurt performance, I suspect this may be the source of many of my problems.

What is going on? How can I eliminate these failed bindings? The example I provided is as simple as I could make it while still being symptomatic of the problem, but it should just work, shouldn't it? I'm building for .net 4.0, if that makes any difference.

**edit:** The errors may be suppressed if you try building the sample code. In visual studio options -> debugging -> output window -> databinding, see that it is set on "Information".

I have seen [Getting many Binding "Information" in WPF output window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846823/getting-many-binding-information-in-wpf-output-window), but there is no information on what to do about it in there.

Thanks

Comment: I've copied your code, and I'm unable to reproduce the binding errors... Are you recieving the errors when you use exactly the above code?

Comment: @PGallagher: Yes, when using that exact code, it was copied right out of a test project. I guess I'll have to build on another machine laying around to see if its something to do with my environment. I also get the binding messages with random border controls too.

Comment: I read, not directly related to, but another problem regarding binding, that adding too quickly to an Observable Collection could trigger Binding Errors... So, if possible, could you try putting a delay in your `For Each` loop, to see if that resolves it?

Comment: @PGallagher: Adding a delay to the loop doesn't improve anything. I also attempted adding the items to the collection after the window was initialized, also with a loop, and triggered by a button, but the binding errors still persist, in fact that for every addition of an item, a new batch of those errors appear.

Comment: @PGallagher: If you would, go into visual studio options -> debugging -> output window -> databinding, and see that it is set on "Information", I think the default is warning, so you might have the messages suppressed. Thanks.

Comment: You;re quite right! Selecting `Information` shows the Binding Errors you refer to.... I'd not tried changing that option before (I will now!)...

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a few things you can fix to eliminate some of those errors.

1. `Stuff` has a private setter so you will have to set the
   `BindingMode` to `OneWay`
2. `A` has a private setter so you will have to set the
       `BindingMode` to `OneWay`
3. `I` has a fallback value that is not an `int` value

However none of these match the errors you posted, but just some observations

Answer (score 0):

Finding all your binding issues will be time consuming and the following solution is simple.

Just enter the following line of code in your applications constructor.

```
System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level     =System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels.Critical;
```

By adding the above line in constructor the debugger will ignore the binding errors and the performance is improved.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Mike.