# Binding errors in execution time

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to eliminate all my runtime binding errors to speed up my application, but I have some errors that are giving me trouble and I'm not able to solve. 
My main problems reside in an user control that displays 3D content.
I show them in a piece of code:

```
<Viewport3D xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
        x:Name="viewport" ClipToBounds="False" IsHitTestVisible="False">
<Viewport3D.Camera>
    <PerspectiveCamera FieldOfView="45" NearPlaneDistance="0.125" FarPlaneDistance="Infinity" Position="-176.298724337988,214.871512878159,289.862943629443" LookDirection="0.469846310392954,-0.342020143325669,-0.813797681349374" UpDirection="0.171010071662834,0.939692620785908,-0.296198132726024"/>
</Viewport3D.Camera>
    <ModelVisual3D>
    <ModelVisual3D.Content>                    
        <Model3DGroup>
            <Model3DGroup.Transform>
                <Transform3DGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform3D ScaleZ="{Binding CurrentScale}" ScaleY="1" ScaleX="1"/>
                    <RotateTransform3D>
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="0,-1,0" Angle="{Binding CurrentAngle}"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                    <MatrixTransform3D Matrix="1,1,-1,0,1,1,-3,0,0,-1,3,0,0,48,32,1"/>
                </Transform3DGroup>
            </Model3DGroup.Transform>
            <GeometryModel3D x:Name="Box02">
                <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <MeshGeometry3D Positions="1 1 1 "/>
                </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    <DiffuseMaterial Brush="{Binding CurrentColor}"/>
                </GeometryModel3D.Material>
            </GeometryModel3D>
            <Model3DGroup>
                <DirectionalLight Direction="{Binding CurrentLight}" Color="#FFFFFF" x:Name="light"/>
            </Model3DGroup>
        </Model3DGroup>
    </ModelVisual3D.Content>                               
</ModelVisual3D>
</Viewport3D>
```

My bindings are the following, I have got the types in the MSDN (attached at the bindings)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.directionallight.direction(v=vs.110).aspx
Type: System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D

```
public System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D CurrentLight
{
    get { return this.currentLight; }
    set
    {
        this.currentLight = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentLight");
    }
}
protected System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D currentLight;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.scaletransform3d.scalez(v=vs.110).aspx
Type: System.Double

```
public double CurrentScale
{
    get { return this.currentScale; }
    set
    {
        this.currentScale = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentScale");
    }
}
protected double currentScale;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.axisanglerotation3d.angle(v=vs.110).aspx
Type: System.Double

```
public double CurrentAngle
{
    get { return this.currentAngle; }
    set
    {
        this.currentAngle = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentAngle");
    }
}
protected double currentAngle;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.diffusematerial.brush(v=vs.110).aspx
Type: System.Windows.Media.Brush

```
public System.Windows.Media.Brush CurrentColor
{
    get { return this.currentColor; }
    set
    {
        this.currentColor = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentColor");
    }
}
protected System.Windows.Media.Brush currentColor;
```

Although the bindings work correctly the following messages appear at runtime:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=CurrentScale; DataItem=null; target element is 'ScaleTransform3D' (HashCode=27183531); target property is 'ScaleZ' (type 'Double')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=CurrentAngle; DataItem=null; target element is 'AxisAngleRotation3D' (HashCode=2594575); target property is 'Angle' (type 'Double')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=CurrentColor; DataItem=null; target element is 'DiffuseMaterial' (HashCode=7565331); target property is 'Brush' (type 'Brush')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=CurrentLight; DataItem=null; target element is 'DirectionalLight' (HashCode=4095240); target property is 'Direction' (type 'Vector3D')
```

---

After searching in Stackoverflow, ¿I find one solution about using "Fallback values"? Is it the best solution?
[Getting many Binding "Information" in WPF output window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846823/getting-many-binding-information-in-wpf-output-window))

I saw in another thread stack overflow they recommend using the following statement ([How to eliminate Binding “Information” in WPF output window - cannot retrieve value using the binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016542/how-to-eliminate-binding-information-in-wpf-output-window-cannot-retrieve-va/18079727#18079727)):

```
System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels.Critical;
```

Anyway, Why am I getting these errors? I understand that the types I use are correct as I have checked them in the links provided of the MSDN, is it correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see if you have specified the data context of the data binding. Have you added the below code to your constructor? If not, that should be your problem. The data binding needs to know where to get the property from.

```
viewport.DataContext = this;
```

I found [this](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html) article to be very informative in this regard. In particular this paragraph:

> Bindings have both a source and a target; where the binding framework is responsible for handling change notifications from the source and (optionally) the target, keeping the two synchronized. The bindings in our FieldUserControl have a value for the Path, which specifies the target, but what is the source?
>   If you create a binding in XAML but do not specify the source (which is probably the most common use case), the source will be set to the DataContext of the control the binding has been specified on. The DataContext is inherited down the visual tree, from each control's parent to child. The DataContext is most often set to a view model or business / model object, as in our case where the top level control, the MainPage, has its DataContext set to an instance of ModelObject.
>   As a result, the DataContext for FieldUserControl and all of its child elements is also ModelObject. This is why our Value binding is failing. Value is a property of FieldUserControl, not our model object.

Comment: Please improve your answer in order for the OP understand why the solution you provided will be helpful. Also, in the link you've posted, try to retrieve the relevant parts, necessary to backup your answer.

Comment: As I mentioned in the other answer, assigning the DataContext to the viewmodel doesn't delete the binding errors in execution time.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming the properties that you have specified are in a ViewModel.  Try adding your ViewModel as a **Resource** to your User Control and set it as your **Data Context**.

```
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:My.App.ViewModels.Test"

<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModels:YourViewModelClass x:Key="myViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewModel}}">

     <!-- Your XAML Code Here -->

</Grid>
```

Comment: Assigning the viewmodel as DataContext, doesn't avoid the data binding errors in execution time.
I forgot to add it when I extract the code.