# Binding An Observable Collection of Class Objects To a ListBox and UserControl (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

**What I'm trying to do**:

I'm binding a ListBox called "**LBShortcuts**" to a class called "**ShortcutList**", that both inherits `ObservableCollection<T>` and holds objects of the class **Shortcut**. I bind it by setting the ListBox's `DataContext` within the `MainWindow`'s constructor. Then I have a UserControl called **UCShortcut** as a `DataTemplate` which binds a property within the **Shortcut** object. When I click a button on the main window, it should add a shortcut to the ObservableCollection, which should invoke the `CollectionChanged` event, which then should alert the data-bound ListBox to update its list, and then all of its items.

**What is happening:**

Absolutely nothing. When I try to add shortcuts to the list via a button on the window, it adds them to the list, but nothing shows up. I've even registered the MainWindow's object to the `ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` event, but it seems like it doesn't fire, even when I explicitly invoke it. Because of that, nothing shows up in the list.

**What I've tried:**

- I tried to create a custom list class using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` interfaces.
- I tried to debug the binding process using `System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceLevel`, and Setting it in the Immediate window. Can't remember where I went wrong, but it didn't work.
- I tried to change my debug options to show me everything about binding in the WPF application, but all it did was show me worrisome binding failures I had nothing to do with:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=IsInAppMenuExpanded; DataItem=null; target element is 'StackPanel' (Name='ButtonStackPanel'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=ShowLiveVisualTreeCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='ShowLiveVisualTree'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=IsInAppSelectionEnabled; DataItem=null; target element is 'ToggleButton' (Name='InAppSelection'); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=AreLayoutAdornersEnabled; DataItem=null; target element is 'ToggleButton' (Name='LayoutAdorners'); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=IsTrackFocusedElementEnabled; DataItem=null; target element is 'ToggleButton' (Name='TrackFocusedElement'); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')
```

...I don't even *have* Toggle buttons in this application.

- I tried to isolate the binding by removing the DataTempate.
- I tried changing the UCShortcut's TextBlock.Text binding to `{Binding BoundShortcut.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}`
- I tried again using VS' databinding dialog box to get around the same idea: `{Binding BoundShortcut.Name, ElementName=userControl, FallbackValue=Binding Invalid}`

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Based on everything I've read about this, this *should* be working. However...here I am. Help, please?

**Details**:

ListBox (LBShortcuts):

```
<Window xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase">
.
.
.
<ListBox x:Name="LBShortcuts" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" IsManipulationEnabled="True" AllowDrop="True" 
         diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <local:UCShortcut BoundShortcut="{Binding Shortcut}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ListBox code-behind:

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Shortcuts = new ShortcutList();
            Shortcuts.CollectionChanged += SaveList;
            LBShortcuts.DataContext = Shortcuts;
            SavingPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) +
              "\\FolderShortcuts.json";
            OpenList();
        }
```

**ShortcutList** class:

```
    public class ShortcutList : ObservableCollection<Shortcut>
    { 
        public ShortcutList() : base()
        {
            shortcuts = new List<Shortcut>();
        }

        public ShortcutList(List<Shortcut> loadedList) : base()
        {
            shortcuts = new List<Shortcut>();
            foreach (Shortcut sc in loadedList)
            {
                Add(new Shortcut(this,sc.Directory,sc.Name));
            }
        }

        public void AddDirectory(string directory, string name)
        {
          DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
          Shortcut s = new Shortcut(this, di);
          if (shortcuts.Where(x => x.Directory == di.FullName).Count() == 0)
          {
              Add(s);
          }
        }
    }
```

**Shortcut** class:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Shortcut : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Directory { get; set; }
        private string name;

        //This must be a property before you can use it as a data binding path in the properties menu of the design page
        public string Name
        {
            get {return name; }
            set
            {
                if (name != value)
                {
                    name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [NonSerialized]
        public ShortcutList Parent;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string member_name = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(member_name));
        }

        public Shortcut(){ }

        public Shortcut(ShortcutList parent, DirectoryInfo directory)
        {
            Parent = parent;
            Directory = directory.FullName;
            Name = directory.Name;
        }

        public Shortcut(ShortcutList parent, string directory,string name)
        {
            Parent = parent;
            Directory = new DirectoryInfo(directory).FullName;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

**UCShortCut** (UserControl)

XAML:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
    ...
    <TextBlock x:Name="TBkName" Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue=Binding Invalid}"
      Padding="4" Foreground="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}"/>
    ...
</Grid>
```

code-behind:

```
 public partial class UCShortcut : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShortcutProperty;
        public Shortcut BoundShortcut
        {
            get{ return (Shortcut)GetValue(ShortcutProperty); }
            set{ SetValue(ShortcutProperty, value); }
        }

        static UCShortcut()
        {
            ShortcutProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BoundShortcut",
              typeof(Shortcut), typeof(UCShortcut));
        }

        public UCShortcut()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RenameShortcut(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TBxName.Text = TBkName.Text;
            TBkName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            TBxName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            TBxName.Focus();
            TBxName.SelectAll();
        }

        private void ChangeName(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
                {
                    BoundShortcut.Name = TBxName.Text;
                }
                TBkName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                TBxName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                TBxName.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        private void InitBoundShortcut(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BoundShortcut = (Shortcut)DataContext;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this [/getting-many-binding-information-in-wpf-output-window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3846823/10024696). Possible dupilcate of the link.

Comment: @neeleshbodgal...I'm not sure what you wanted me to get from this post. I can't set the fallback values for these, since they're not in my application at all, and if the article Hugo was referencing in the comments below the question give me a 404. Additionally, this isn't a outstandingly relevant part of my main question.

Comment: Besides the things mentioned in the question, your ShortcutList declaration looks odd. Why is there a "backing" list, when the class is already derived from ObservableCollection?

Comment: @Skello You are creating an empty observation collection. check the MainWindow constructor. Adding items to collection is not showing anywhere

Comment: @Clemens: Oh! Sorry. Please ignore that. That was an artifact from attempt 1 (see "What I've tried"). I forgot to remove it when I put the class back how it was. That list is not actually being used in the application.

Comment: @neeleshbodgal: If you check the ShortcutList class, you'll see a method that says AddDirectory(). I left it blank inside, since it wasn't relevant to the question. It does, indeed, add shortcuts to the list. The problem was getting them to appear.

Comment: @Skello Still we have no idea whether items aren't shown at all, or if they are just empty.

Comment: @Clemens: The items aren't showing because they don't exist....? Since the binding isn't working correctly, the ListBox doesn't make any UCShortcut objects, so the list is empty. Besides, that I tried the ObservableCollection, thing, and it works.

Comment: So, obviously your ShortcutList class is broken.  And `Text="{Binding Name ...}"` would directly bind to the object in the DataContext. You wouldn't need to declare the BoundShortcut property then. It is hence nonsense and should be replaced by `Text="{Binding BoundShortcut.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}`

Comment: @Clemens: The BoundShortcut was for the Data template to latch onto the dataContext there. Are you saying that the binding automatically makes the data template's dataContext whatever it inherited from ListBox?

Comment: Sure it does. The DataContext of a ListBoxItem is automatically set to the respective element of the ItemsSource collection. And the DataContext is inherited by the elements in the DataTemplate, i.e. your UserControl - otherwise `BoundShortcut="{Binding Shortcut}"` would not work.

Comment: If that's the case, why should I have to set the DataContext programmatically at all? Why is it even an option? Is ItemsSource just DataContext? Why are they different names and properties if they're the same thing? @_@ I'm so confused. Also, where did you go to learn this? I exhausted Microsoft's documentation, at least, as much as I could find, and they do not go into this level of detail on Binding, claiming it's simple, when it clearly isn't.

Comment: You don't set the DataContext of the ListBoxItem, but only the DataContext of the ListBox (or better, that of the MainWindow). Nothing else, the rest is done by the framework. I can recommend *WPF Unleashed* - a book by Adam Nathan.

Comment: I have that exact book....He's the reason why I'm here.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).